# Concrete application of Caratheodory extension

Tags: measure-theory

I am working on the following problem:

**Question:**

> Let $\Omega$ be an uncountable set. Denote by $\mathfrak{R}$ the ring
> of finite subsets of $\Omega$. Consider the measure $\mu: \mathfrak{R}
>  \rightarrow [0, + \infty]: E \mapsto 0$. What is in this case the
> outer measure $\mu^{*}$ (induced by $\mu$) and the associated
> $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}$? What is the
> $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ generated by $\mathfrak{R}$? Is the
> extension of the measure $\mu$ from $\mathfrak{R}$ to $\mathfrak{M}$
> obtained via the Caratheodory procedure the only possible extension?

**Attempt:** First recall some definitions. By definition, $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}} = \left\{ E \subset \Omega \mid E \ \text{is} \ \mu^{*}\text{-measurable} \right\}$. And a set $E \subset \Omega$ is $\mu^{*} \text{-measurable}$  if for all $A \subset \Omega$, we have $$ \mu^{*} (A) = \mu^{*} (A \cap E) + \mu^{*} (A \cap E^c). $$ Also, recall how $\mu^{*}$ is defined: For each $E \subset \Omega$ we have $$ \mu^{*} (E) := \text{inf} \left\{ \sum_n \mu(E_n) \mid (E_n)_n \in \mathfrak{R} \ \text{is a sequence with} \ E \subset \bigcup_n E_n \right\}. $$

In this specific question, I think we have $$  \mu^{*} (E) =  \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ E \ \text{is finite or countable infinite} \\ + \infty & \text{if} \ E \ \text{is uncountable} \end{cases} $$
However, I am stuck with finding $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}$ and $\mathfrak{M}$. I know from a theorem that $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}$ will contain $\mathfrak{R}$. I also know that in general, $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}$ will be a bigger set than $\mathfrak{M}$. By definition, $\mathfrak{M}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathfrak{R}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us go step by step

$1$. The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ generated by $\mathfrak{R}$.

Since every countable subset of $\Omega$ is the countable union of finite sets (singletons), we have that every countable subset of $\Omega$ is in $\mathfrak{M}$.

Then it is easy to see that
$$\mathfrak{M} =\{ E \subseteq \Omega : E \textrm{ or } E^c \textrm{ is countable }\}$$

$2$. The outer measure $\mu^{*}$.

It is exactly as you wrote: For each $E \subset \Omega$ we have $$ \mu^{*} (E) := \text{inf} \left\{ \sum_n \mu(E_n) \mid (E_n)_n \in \mathfrak{R} \ \text{is a sequence with} \ E \subset \bigcup_n E_n \right\}. $$

In this specific question, we have $$  \mu^{*} (E) =  \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ E \ \text{is finite or countable infinite} \\ + \infty & \text{if} \ E \ \text{is uncountable} \end{cases} $$
because an uncountable subset can not be covered by a countable collection of finite subsets.

$3$. The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}$.

We have that, for all $E \subset \Omega$, $E \in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}$  if and only if for all $A \subset \Omega$, we have $$ \mu^{*} (A) = \mu^{*} (A \cap E) + \mu^{*} (A \cap E^c). $$

For any $E \subset \Omega$, we have:

If $A$ is uncountable, then $A \cap E$ or $ A \cap E^c$ is also uncountable and we get

$$ \mu^{*} (A) =+\infty = \mu^{*} (A \cap E) + \mu^{*} (A \cap E^c). $$

If $A$ is countable, then $A \cap E$ and $ A \cap E^c$ are both countable and we get

$$ \mu^{*} (A) =0 = 0+0 = \mu^{*} (A \cap E) + \mu^{*} (A \cap E^c). $$

So $\mathfrak{M}_{\mu^{*}}= 2^\Omega =\{ E : E \subseteq \Omega\}$.

$4$. Is the extension of the measure $\mu$ from $\mathfrak{R}$ to $\mathfrak{M}$ obtained via the Caratheodory procedure the only possible extension?

Answer: No.

Let $\mu_1$ be the extension of the measure $\mu$ from $\mathfrak{R}$ to $\mathfrak{M}$ obtained via the Caratheodory procedure. Then

$$  \mu_1(E) =  \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ E \ \text{is countable} \\ + \infty & \text{if} \ E^c \ \text{is countable} \end{cases} $$

Another extension would be $\mu_2$ defined by $\mu_2(E)=0$, for all $E \in \mathfrak{M}$.

Note tha, since $\Omega$ is uncountable, $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. So it does not need to have a unique extension to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ generated by $\mathfrak{R}$.